# Yelp review API response

Tags: python, api

I am working with Yelp API reviews. I get the responses for each business id using the code

```
 id='amys-ice-creams-austin-3'
    
    response = yelp_api.reviews_query(id='amys-ice-creams-austin-3')
    type(response).
```

(1) But suppose, if I have 300 business ids, how do get it as a response as a dictionary using simple code.

(2) Is there a way as well to put it in a dataframe.

```
cols = list(responses['reviews'][0].keys())
reviews = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
for biz in responses['reviews']:
    reviews = reviews.append(biz, ignore_index=True)
reviews.head()
```

which does not work.
Help please.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simple? A dictionary comprehension.

```
ids = ['a', 'b', 'c']
responses = {
    business_id: yelp_api.reviews_query(business_id)
    for business_id in ids
}
```

However, should the API fail for any given request (e.g. you get rate limited), you get no data at all. Error handling is simpler with a simple for loop:

```
responses = {}
for business_id in ids:
    try:
        responses[business_id] = yelp_api.reviews_query(business_id)
    except Exception as exc:
        print(f"Failed retrieving {business_id}: {exc}")
        # TODO: maybe retry this fetch?
```

## EDIT

According to the image in the updated original post, you might really want a flat list of review dicts with the business ID included:

```
reviews = []
for business_id in ids:
    try:
        response = yelp_api.reviews_query(business_id)["reviews"]
    except Exception as exc:
        print(f"Failed retrieving {business_id}: {exc}")
        # TODO: maybe retry this fetch?
        continue
    for review in response:
        # Merge the business ID into the dict, append to a list.
        reviews.append({**review, "business_id": business_id})
```

The list should be convertible into a dataframe with `pd.DataFrame(reviews)`.

Comment: Thank you. I got it. But when I try to put it in a dataframe it does not work. I am using the code,  cols = list(responses['reviews'][0].keys())
reviews = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
for biz in responses['reviews']:
    reviews = reviews.append(biz, ignore_index=True)
reviews.head()

Comment: KeyError: 'reviews' is coming up.

Comment: I don't know what the data is you get from `reviews_query`, but you'll probably need to further massage the dict-of-dicts? you get into a flat list-of-dicts before you can try just appending it to a dataframe.

Comment: Ok, managed to do it with different code. But many thanks.